# Prevent Overflow Horizontal Scroll on page

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I am viewing this site http://alchuang.com/mamaclub/ on Chrome using Windows 7, I see a horizontal scroll bar on the page. It seems like there's an additional margin to the right that is causing this, but scanning through the CSS by inspecting the elements, I can't seem to find the cause. Could it be jQuery from the carousel?

It is possible to correct it by applying `overflow: hidden` on the `<body>` tag but I prefer to isolate the cause and rectify it.

Your help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: did u apply html,body{ margin:0; padding :0; } in start

Comment: The `#jquery` tag is not relevant here. This is a LESS/CSS concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 100% width, absolutely positioned div is causing it:

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height: 500px;/* background-color:black */background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 2%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 44%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(2%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(44%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 2%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 44%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 2%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 44%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 2%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 44%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */  background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 2%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 44%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */;"></div>
```

This is happening because 100% width is counted to body which is bigger (carousel).

Add `position: relative` to container marketing to count width relatively to container not body.

Answer (score 1):

I did these changes and it worked for me:

on `<div class="container">`, I set width to 100% instead of the amount of fixed pixels it had.

on `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">` (the header), set `margin-left` to `200px`
and `margin-right` to `200px`

of course it is not exactly the same as before, as you should change those 200px to the correct ones

that way the scrollbar disappears

edit: but somehow the content stretches a bit on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

It is my suspicion that this is caused by a mismatched element (i.e. an opening tag without a matching close tag). This is a common symptom, though it's nearly impossible to detect through the browser because most modern browsers will auto-fix this.

**[EDIT]** Just took a closer look at your LESS, looks like you *have* addressed the following. I'll leave it in here just in case anyone else visits the page looking for a similar solution.

---

<strike>Meanwhile, be sure that you have</strike>

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

~in your CSS; this ensures that everything is only as wide as its `width` says it will be (borders/padding don't dilate the element) and that the body and HTML itself has no external margin (there is often some built-in margin in the browser).